# How can I host one or more json files on google app engine?

Tags: json, ajax, web-services, google-app-engine

So I recently tried storing a json file on my website server to call from a mobile app. Unfortunately it was way too slow to use. I turned to Google and thought I might be able to host the json file on Google App Engine and hopefully speed it up. Is this possible, and if so how? I have never used Google App Engine before.

If there are better solutions out there, please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrei suggests the Google Cloud Storage is probably the best option for your use case, however, if you insists on App Engine, it is also possible.

Moreover, for efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files from dedicated servers and caches that are separate from the application servers.

You have to configure the static file handlers for your app and you are done.

> Static file handlers describe which files in the application directory
>   are static files, and which URLs serve them.

You can find an example below or more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers).

**app.yaml**

```
application: app
version: v1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# All URLs beginning with /static are treated as paths to static files in the static/ directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store this file on Google Cloud Storage, which is specifically designed for efficient storage and caching of files.

You can simply upload this file to a new bucket. If it's publicly available, you won't have to write any code at all. If you want to keep it private, then you will need to load it from your app using a signed URL.

You can find all the necessary information in [Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and tutorials.

Comment: Sounds like something I could use. I created the bucket and dropped in my json file and shared that file publicly. How can I access that url to make an ajax call?

Comment: Hmm..think I found it but I am getting a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.

Comment: It may indicate a problem with how you read the file. Take a look: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: Is there a way to enable CORS from Google cloud storage?

Comment: I see how to set CORS with gsutil, but where do I actually drop the cors.xml file?

Comment: You don't need it if you use gsutil.

Comment: So I wrote the command: gsutil cors set gs://BUCKET_NAME and the error came back as "CommandException: "cors" command spanning providers not allowed."